# Can a non-convex feasible set have zero duality gap?

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I have been reading about strong duality. I understood that strong duality exists for convex functions(almost always) and non convex feasible sets has non zero duality gap. But is there a possibility that -- the feasible set is not convex, but has zero duality gap ? If yes, please explain with some examples.

Comment: Yes. Take, for example, this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0465.pdf

Comment: Is it not right to generalize that non convex feasible set have always non zero duality gap?